# Error generic array creation

Tags: java

```
public class TwoBridge implements Piece{
    private HashSet<Hexagon>[] permutations;

    public TwoBridge(){
        permutations = new HashSet<Hexagon>[6];
```

Hi, I'm trying to create an array of Sets of hexagons (hexagons being a class i created).

However I get this error when I try to compile

```
oliver@oliver-desktop:~/uni/16/partB$ javac oadams_atroche/TwoBridge.java 
oadams_atroche/TwoBridge.java:10: generic array creation
        permutations = new HashSet<Hexagon>[6];
                       ^
1 error
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create arrays with generics. Use a `Collection<Set<Hexagon>>` or `(Array)List<Set<Hexagon>>` instead.

Here's the [formal explanation](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. The best you can do is make an `ArrayList<Set<Hexagon>>`.

<sub><sup>If you are willing to deal with raw types (which are heavily discouraged), you can make an array of `Set` (as opposed to `Set<Hexagon>`, which is not allowed). But you didn't hear this from me.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

Following will give you a warning:

`permutations = new HashSet[6];`

However, I agree with Chris that it is better to use ArrayList instead of ordinary array.