# How do you instantiate a Map.Entry<K, V> array in Java?

Tags: java, generics, casting, subtype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Generics: Array containing generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044309/java-generics-array-containing-generics)

I have a Java class which contains 2 methods which add and remove an element from an array. To make it generic it takes a subtype so it should be able to work on different types of objects.

The problem is that when I instantiate it using MapEntry (where MapEntry is an implementation of java.util.Map.Entry) as the subtype. This results in a ClassCastException being thrown when trying to convert an Object array to a MapEntry array. I'm guessing this is because of the following lines (Where T is the subtype):

```
array = (T[])(new Object[array.length + 1]);
array = (T[])(new Object[array.length - 1]);
```

Which are used to increase/decrease the array size by 1 respectively. I also use this on arrays of Integers, Strings and Objects, and it works fine with those.

Also, it's explicitly stated that I need to use arrays for this, so no lists, etc.

Is there any way to get around this problem while still keeping the class as generic as possible?

Edit: Managed to get the problem solved. Here's the working code:

```
array = (T[])Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), array.length + 1);
array = (T[])Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), array.length - 1);
```

Thanks for all the help :D

Comment: Casting to `T` shouldn't really do anything, at least not if the type parameter is unbound. Could you provide a little more context? The type signature of your class and how you're instantiating it?

Comment: That said, you cannot have generic arrays and shouldn't try to do so. I'd use an `Object[]` throughout and just cast when returning values in your methods – it's still an unsafe cast but it's a little more localised. (Or look at how `ArrayList` is implemented and do that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) don't use arrays, they are awful. Use collections instead.

B) you can't create a generic array without knowing the array type. if you do have the type (the class), you can do:

```
T[] array = Array.newInstance(type, length);
```

Read:

- [`Array.newInstance(class, length)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29)
- [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Comment: A) As stated in the problem, I'm doing this for an assignment and it explicitly states I have to use arrays :(
    
B) Could you please elaborate on this? If you have to know the array type to create the array, wouldn't this take away the whole point of generics?

Comment: @user1097658 yes, but unfortunately Java generics work that way. Read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: This helped me solve the problem. See my edit in the question. Thanks :P

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Regarding point A, if only we could easily pass a collection into a varargs parameter without converting it into an array, I would be happy to comply =)  (I'm looking at you, `Map.ofEntries()` )

Answer (score 0):

A `T[]` array is a subclass of `Object[]`, and you may the cast `T[]` to `Object[]`. But the reverse is false: you can't cast an `Object[]` to `T[]` because `Object[]` is not a subclass of `T[]`.

I think your question boils down to [How to create an array of a generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)?