# Convert an entrySet to an array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, collections, dictionary

I'd like to convert the `entrySet()` of an `Map<String, Statistic>` to an `array` (or ArrayList).

I tried:

```
Map.Entry<String, Statistic>[] entries = statisticMap.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry<String, Statistic>[0]);
```

but this gives the compiler error:
"Cannot create a generic array of  Map.Entry"

Even this does not work, with same error:

```
Map.Entry<String, Statistic>[] entries = new Map.Entry<String, Statistic>[1];
```

But this works:

```
Map.Entry[] entries = new Map.Entry[1];
```

Any ideas how to create such a array or list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you instantiate a Map.Entry<K, V> array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504045/how-do-you-instantiate-a-map-entryk-v-array-in-java)

Comment: The above anwer in the duplicate is less suitable than Peters answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any ideas how to create such a array or list?

You can do this, though it is ugly.

```
Map.Entry<String, Statistic>[] entries = 
                          (Map.Entry<String, Statistic>[]) new Map.Entry[num];
```

Comment: Yes its ugly, and it shows that there is a better solution in my App using a SortedMap

Answer (score 7):

If you're willing to get a list instead of an array, you can do this:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Statistic>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
```

Using a list avoids the problems creating arrays of generics, and it also lets you use the "diamond operator" of Java 7 to avoid repeating the type arguments.

Answer (score -2):

Well, the root reason for complication is the broken Java design, compared to C#, where Array and List doesn't implement the same interface. So, any solution will be ugly (and with performance penalty).

If going ugly, personally I prefer explicit solutions, where at least you can see whats actually going on.

Therefore, my ugly version is:

```
Map.Entry<String, String>[] keys = new Map.Entry[map.entrySet().size()];

int index = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: map.entrySet()) {

     keys[index] = entry;
     index++;
}
```