# how to new a List<Integer>[] in java

Tags: java

```
public class XXXX{
    private List<Integer>[] a;
    public XXXX(int num)
    {
        a = new ....?
    } 
}
```

How should i new the *a* ?

Comment: Arrays and generics don't go well together.

Comment: what is a? is it a array of List<Integer>

Comment: Why would you even need such a construct? (apart from an interview or exam question...)

Comment: You cannot create an array of a parameterised type in Java. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903196/error-generic-array-creation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize Java Generic Array of Type Generic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025837/initialize-java-generic-array-of-type-generic)

Comment: Please do a thorough search on SO for your questions before asking them 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java

Answer (score 4):

NPE: "Arrays and generics don't go well together"

Go for list of lists

```
List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

or double array

```
int[][] a = new int[5][5];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create an array of lists but you cannot use type during initalization.

```
List<Integer>[] lists=new List[10];

//insertion
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    lists[i]=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    lists[i].add(i);
    lists[i].add(i+1);
}

//printing
for(List<Integer> list:lists){
    System.out.println(list.size());
}
```

Why this works? Because the `lists` variable points to an array data structure whose data type is `List<Integer>`. This array contains a set of references to different objects of type `List<Integer>`, and this is why if we try to run `lists[i]=new ArrayList<String>();` it will not compile. However when we initialize the array itself we don't need to provide the type of the List objects as List since from JVM point of view a List of Integer objects and a List of Object objects will require the same number of bytes as logn as their sizes is same. The only constraint comes when we set a array member to a value (of type List - it has to be `List<Integer>` not anything else)

You can type cast the `List[]` to a `List<Integer>[]` but the end result and the JVM behavior is the same.

Comment: why would someone need this mess?

Comment: In production level java nobody would require this (we are all about Collections and Collections of Collections) but it's good food for thought.

Comment: nobody uses arrays unless they 'need' to work with primitives. arrays in java might have been useful if they were kept in stack.

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
int arraySize = 10;
List<Integer>[] a = (List<Integer>[]) new List[arraySize];
```

It create an array (of size 10) that can contains List of Integer

Comment: Don't bother reading the initial comments as they refer to an incorrect link and people asking why why why.   This worked perfectly, simple question and simple answer. I was grouping my four List<Integer> together and an array was the perfect choice. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = (List<Integer>[]) new List[num];
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    a[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Really though, why not declare `a` as a `List<List<Integer>>`?

Answer (score 0):

you can do as `List<Integer> a=new ArrayList<Integer>();`
but a should not be generic

Answer (score -3):

List is an interface in java!

you can give references of instances like ArrayList, linket list, vector and stack to a variable with List datatype

so you can use one of the following,

```
a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a = new LinkedList<Integer>();
a = new Vector()<Integer>;
a = new Stack()<Integer>;
```

Comment: Look closely at the question. `a` is an **array** of lists. Java does not allow you to make an array of a parameterised type.

Comment: yes you are right jasper! i did not observe keenly!

Comment: And what is with the syntax on the last two?