# how can I implement the constructor of a hashtable in java

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

Suppose I need to implement a hashtable on my own,but I have some problems about implementing my constructor. For example,if I need to initialize List[] buckets,but when I write like the following codes,the computer just gave a wrong signal of"buckets[i]=new List()"   , can someone tell me how to finish the constructor in this case?
import java.util.List;

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class GeneralHashMap extends MyHashMap {

  public List< String>[] buckets;

  public GeneralHashMap() {
    for(int i=0;i<120;i++)
    {
        buckets[i]=new List<String>(); 
    }

    // TODO: IMPLEMENT CONSTRUCTOR

  }


  public GeneralHashMap(int newsize)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<newsize;i++)
    {
        buckets[i]=new List<String>();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected int hash(String token) {

    // TODO: IMPLEMENT HASHING FUNCTION FOR GENERAL HASHMAP
    return -1;

  }

  @Override
  public void add(String token) {

    // TODO: IMPLEMENT ADD METHOD USING BUCKETS

  }

  @Override
  public void display() {

    // TODO: IMPLEMENT DISPLAY METHOD TO SHOW CONTENTS OF ALL BUCKETS

  }

}
```

Comment: I want to set up a list of list<string> so that I can store strings in every bucket,but I have some problems to implement the construct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java `List` is just an interface which cannot be instantiated. What you need is a class implementing such interface, for example, `ArrayList`. Try

```
buckets = new List[120];
for(int i=0;i<120;i++)
{
    buckets[i]=new ArrayList<String>(); 
}
```

Comment: would also be worth mentioning the initialization of the `new List[120]` rather than just including it. The second constructor also needs one.

Answer (score 0):

initialize your `public List< String>[] buckets;` properly before filling it:

```
public List< String>[] buckets = new ArrayList< String>[120];
```

Comment: That won't work for the second constructor if a size > 120 is passed - you should initialize in the constructor instead

Comment: oops, you're right, didn't saw the other constructor

Comment: Oh and `List` isn't a class, so you need a concrete implementation

Comment: And also `new ArrayList< String>[120];` is not valid... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903196/error-generic-array-creation